# Как отрендерить картинки из mock-файла в React?

Tags: reactjs, изображения

коллеги!
У меня проект на React и задача вывести из массива объектов картинку, ее описание и все, что к ней относится.
Обычно картинки импортируются так: import {image} from 'path';
Но мне необходимо отрендерить большое количество картинок.
Вот что у меня получилось (не получилось в итоге):

В файле myJson.js лежит такой объект:

```
const myJson = {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Landscape of Saint-Remy",
        "path": "./../../images/art/a.jpg",
        "cost": 400,
        "materials": "oil",
        "canvas": "canvas",
        "width": 40,
        "height": 30,
        "depth": 2,
        "description": "The painting is based on the work of Vincent Van Gogh",
        "tags": ["Vincent van Gogh",
        "scenery",
        "expressionism",
        "impressionism",
        "field",
        "the mountains",
        "forest",
        "sky",
        "clouds",
        "grass",
        "Spring",
        "summer"],
        "sold": false,
        "year": 2016,
        "style": "expressionism"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Landscape of Saint-Remy",
        "path": "./../../a.jpg",
        "cost": 400,
        "materials": "oil",
        "canvas": "canvas",
        "width": 40,
        "height": 30,
        "depth": 2,
        "description": "The painting is based on the work of Vincent Van Gogh",
        "tags": ["Vincent van Gogh",
        "scenery",
        "expressionism",
        "impressionism",
        "field",
        "the mountains",
        "forest",
        "sky",
        "clouds",
        "grass",
        "Spring",
        "summer"],
        "sold": false,
        "year": 2016,
        "style": "expressionism"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Landscape of Saint-Remy",
        "path": "./../../a.jpg",
        "cost": 400,
        "materials": "oil",
        "canvas": "canvas",
        "width": 40,
        "height": 30,
        "depth": 2,
        "description": "The painting is based on the work of Vincent Van Gogh",
        "tags": ["Vincent van Gogh",
        "scenery",
        "expressionism",
        "impressionism",
        "field",
        "the mountains",
        "forest",
        "sky",
        "clouds",
        "grass",
        "Spring",
        "summer"],
        "sold": false,
        "year": 2016,
        "style": "expressionism"
      }
    ]
  }
```

export default myJson;

В компоненте Home я пытаюсь его получить и отрендерить картинки:

import React from 'react';
import myJson from '../../server/myJson';

function Home() {
return (

{myJson.data.map(key => (
<img src={require(`${key.path}`)} key={key} />
))}

);

export default Home;

Но получаю ошибку - Error: Cannot find module './../../images/art/a.jpg'
Просто через пути вот так тоже не получается отрендерить:

```
        {myJson.data.map(key => (
     <img src={key.path} key={key} />
```

ошибки нет, путь к картинке проверила - поместила ее в папку компонента Home и путь в myJSON изменила на './a.jpg';
Ответ 200ок - но картинка не рендерится.
Коллеги, помогите, пожалуйста.